# Single Array Dimension using Double in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've been keeping on try about declaring the one dimensional single array with the following code :

```
double[] temporary= {0.7143, 0.5392, 0.5444, 0.5321, 0.5417, 0.5528, 0.5327, 0.5267, 0.5271};
```

and the code has been running flawless but the problem occurs every time I try to declare as a dynamic value. Perhaps I've no idea how to declare it properly.

This what I've been trying recently :

```
double temporary[];
temporary = new double[1000];
```

The following code I've tried and attempted with fixed size :

```
for (int i = 0; i < window.length; i++)
            {
                window[i] = temporary[j + i - windowSize];
            }
```

This with array list :

```
for (int i = 0; i < window.length; i++)
            {
                window[i] = temporary.get(j+i-windowSize);
            }
```

All I want to just declare the empty double array and fill it dynamically as I mentioned above.

Thank you very much

Comment: Normally this should have worked. what error message are you getting, while running this code?

Comment: Is the problem that you want the specific values in the array to vary dynamically, or that you want the *size* of the array (that is, how many elements it contains) to vary? You're fast accumulating desperate answers here but the question itself is not clear.

Comment: For the record, in less than ten minutes, we have eight answers to a non-question. What's the incentive driving this rush?

Comment: Please check the following code

Comment: @YosepKurniaWijaya What's window? What's usd? You're only giving us more questions.

Comment: @seh a lot of people appreciate and want to help and not to do some cheesy chat. Appreciate people those who help. Thank you. I appreciate you all. God bless

Comment: You are not filling `temporary` double array here, but a `window` array which we can't see here..

Comment: Show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), not snippets out-of-context...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use ArrayList for that.

```
ArrayList<Double> temporary = new ArrayList<Double>();
temporary.add(0.46567);
...
```

The problem is that a normal array in Java, such as `double[]` have a fixed size. You can only set the size of an array once, while using ArrayList, you can add and remove elements whenever you'd like.

Comment: I've tried also as your following code. But the problem always occurs when I do mentioned accessing the array and everything just messed up. :(

Comment: @Stefan an array does not grow, an array has a fixed size. You can only set the size of an array once.

Comment: @YosepKurniaWijaya Then you are probably making a mistake when trying to use arraylists. Show your attempts of using an ArrayList and we'll can help you with how to use it properly.

Comment: Defining the variable using interface, not implementation, would be better style in Java: `List<Double> temporary = …`

Comment: @Simon: This is indeed true - but if I use a new "new"-Statement, I can create a new array with a different size! As I said before, if you need something that grows, array is not the right choice. But if you just need something with a new fixed size, than you can still use an array and create a new one..

Comment: @Stefan actually you said "If I need something that grows, than an array is not the wrong structure." earlier. And now you say "array is not the right choice." Typo? :) Creating a new array whenever you'd like to change the size of it is not very efficient.

Comment: lol yeah definetely a typo don't know what was in my mind.. maybe the dogs fart? blame me ;) At least now it is clear what I wanted to say.. ohoh..

Comment: Hello Stefan, no offense. However, I'd rather appreciate Simon's answer than arguing some simple statement. Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what Stefan had to say. Once he said the right thing of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of content ahead of time, then it would be something like;

```
temporary = new double[sizeofContent];
```

If you don't know the content length ahead of time, then you may need to use something like `list` (which is sort of dynamic) and then covert it to `array` using `toArray(type)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList for that :

```
List<Double> temporary = new ArrayList<Double>();
temporary.add(0.5588);
```

Answer (score 0):

double[] temporary = new double[1000];

To initialise use like

temporary[0] = 2.456d;

hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically need random access, prefer LinkedList over ArrayList. Indeed, it will avoid multiple resizing of your array (when reaching capacity) as long as this one grows:

```
List<Double> temporary = new LinkedList<Double>();
temporary.add(0.46567);
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

use a collections object like `ArrayList`,

```
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
doubles.add(...);
doubles.add(...);
...
Double[] temp = doubles.toArray(new Double[0]);
```

Comment: love how this gets downvoted in favor of something that suggests using a fixed size array with an empty counter. brilliant.